# How to cleanly exit a jni application on Android (SDL2)

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, sdl

I have written a C++ application using SDL2, I am using the SDL provided JNI handler:

https://www.libsdl.org/tmp/SDL/android-project/src/org/libsdl/app/SDLActivity.java

I am just extending this to call main on my native code:

```
package com.test.testapp;

import org.libsdl.app.SDLActivity;

public class Testapp extends SDLActivity
{

}
```

A few things I've tried:

- If I let main return normally, I notice that Android throws a UI error and my app is still running
- After adding some shutdown handling, in my native application:

--

```
 SQL_Quit();
   std::exit(0);
```

--

That appears to kill the process according to logcat:

--

```
2-19 10:03:27.344  2125  2142 I SDL/APP : ==================================================== 
12-19 10:03:27.344  2125  2142 I SDL/APP : GameInstance::shutdown -- shutting down... 
12-19 10:03:27.360  2125  2142 I SDL/APP : GameInstance::shutdown -- shutdown complete, exiting... 
12-19 10:03:27.360  2125  2142 I SDL/APP : ==================================================== 
12-19 10:03:27.465   911  4440 D GraphicsStats: Buffer count: 6
12-19 10:03:27.465   911  4439 I WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{e8e4c8d u0 com.test.testapp/com.test.testapp.Testapp}
12-19 10:03:27.465   911  4439 W WindowManager: Force-removing child win Window{27798bc u0 SurfaceView - com.test.testapp/com.test.testapp.Testapp} from container Window{e8e4c8d u0 com.test.testapp/com.test.testapp.Testapp}
12-19 10:03:27.465   911 19431 I sensors : activate
12-19 10:03:27.466   911 26120 I ActivityManager: Process com.test.testapp (pid 2125) has died
12-19 10:03:27.466   911  4439 I WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=SurfaceView - com.test.testapp/com.test.testapp.Testapp) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2014 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:881 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeLocked:1449 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowInnerLocked:2478 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowInnerLocked:2457 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2436 com.android.server.wm.WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied:1780 android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice:688 
12-19 10:03:27.466   911 26120 D ActivityManager: cleanUpApplicationRecord -- 2125
12-19 10:03:27.466   911 26120 W ActivityManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{c279606 u0 com.test.testapp/.Testapp t766}: app died, no saved state
12-19 10:03:27.467   911 19431 I nanohub : queueActivate: sensor=1, handle=1, enable=0
12-19 10:03:27.469   911  4439 I WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=com.test.testapp/com.test.testapp.Testapp) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2014 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:881 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeLocked:1449 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowInnerLocked:2478 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2436 com.android.server.wm.WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied:1780 android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice:688 <bottom of call stack> 
12-19 10:03:27.472   911  6772 W WindowManager: Failed looking up window
12-19 10:03:27.472   911  6772 W WindowManager: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window android.os.BinderProxy@ff7be42 does not exist
12-19 10:03:27.472   911  6772 W WindowManager:     at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:9100)
12-19 10:03:27.472   911  6772 W WindowManager:     at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:9091)
12-19 10:03:27.472   911  6772 W WindowManager:     at com.android.server.wm.WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied(WindowState.java:1777)
12-19 10:03:27.472   911  6772 W WindowManager:     at android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice(Binder.java:688)
12-19 10:03:27.472   911  6772 I WindowManager: WIN DEATH: null
```

However after doing this, I notice that my Application window is still present in Android Window history. I'm not sure what the correct term for this is, but the square button on my device gives me a list of all open windows. When I select my application from this list it actually restarts it (because it's killed) but I would like to also remove the window from here as it gives the appearance that it's still running.

Comment: AFAIK Android "window history" doesn't keep only active/running apps, but all last opened. I don't really know if you can remove your app from there. Check [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/memory-overview.html#SwitchingApps) and [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) for more info about least-recently used (LRU) cache.

Comment: Ah I see, I have some reading to do to understand Android a bit better. Thanks Oskar

Comment: Glad I could help you!